# How to create combination pairs (of bigrams) from a pair of input strings?

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, combinations, n-gram

I have 2 input strings and I want to generate all the combinations of pairs of strings in which each string is from **different input string**.

Example:
Input strings:

> "womens dresses" and "ladies gown"

For combinations, I want to limit strings to n=2 (bigrams).

Expected output:

> womens - ladies, womens - gown, dresses - ladies, dresses - gown,
>   womens dresses - ladies, womens dresses - gown, womens dresses -
>   ladies gown, ladies gown - womens and ladies gown - dresses

Comment: Shouldn't your output have only 4 members (the Cartesian product of the first string and second string)? Could you explain the rules for generating the rest of the output?

Comment: So the problem statement is to assume that both input strings are related in some way and we need to identify potential synonym candidates from them. So any word OR combination of 2 words can be related in some way to any word OR combination of 2 words from other string. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing cross product of all possible substrings(upto length 2) of both the input strings.

Example: If our input strings are `"1 2"` and `"3 4"`

Then,

All substrings of input string 1 till length 2  = `sub1 = {"1", "2", "1 2"}`

All substrings of input string 2 till length 2  = `sub2 = {"3", "4", "3 4"}`

Solution = Cross Product of `sub1` and `sub2`
         = {("1","3"), ("1","4"), ("1","3 4"), ("2","3"), ("2","4"), ("2","3 4"), ("1 2","3"), ("1 2","4"), ("1 2","3 4")}

Methods used:

```
 //create subsets of length 1 AND 2 (bigrams)
  private def createSubSets(str: String): List[String] = {
    val arr = str.split(" ").filter(StringUtils.isNotBlank(_)).toSet[String]
    var subsets = arr.subsets(1).map(_.mkString).toList
    if(arr.size > 1) subsets ++= arr.subsets(2).map(_.mkString(" ")).toList
    subsets
  }

  private def generateSynonymCandidatesFromPair(str1: String, str2: String): List[(String, String)] ={
    createSubSets(str1).flatMap(s1 => createSubSets(str2).map(s2 => (s1, s2)))
  }
```